# Laravel eloquent realationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

This is my problem.

I have a model called Product that defines a relation like this

Product.php

```
public function maintenanceById($maintenanceId){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Maintenance::class, 'product_maintenance')->where('maintenance_id', '=', $maintenanceId)->withPivot(['price', 'code']);
    }
```

I use this method in a view like so

```
    @foreach($maintenance as $value)

        @if($product->maintenanceById($value->id)->getResults())
          <th>
           {{$product->maintenanceById($value->id)->getResults()[0]->pivot->price}}
          </th>
       @else
          <th></th>
       @endif

   @endforeach
```

`getResults` returns an array that has a single object in it so I have to access the object within using `getResults()[0]`. Is there a way to make the returned value into an object so I can simply do this:

```
$product->maintenanceById($value->id)->getResults()->pivot->price
```

EDIT:
Ive tried this and it works

```
public function maintenanceById($maintenanceId){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Maintenance::class, 'product_maintenance')->where('maintenance_id', '=', $maintenanceId)->withPivot(['price', 'code'])->get();
}
```

Then in the view

```
@foreach($maintenance as $value)
   @if(!$product->maintenanceById($value->id)->isEmpty())
      <th>£ {{$product->maintenanceById($value->id)->first()->pivot->price}}</th>
  @else
      <th></th>
  @endif
@endforeach
```

But when I try the following code it doesn't work.

```
public function maintenanceById($maintenanceId){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Maintenance::class, 'product_maintenance')->where('maintenance_id', '=', $maintenanceId)->withPivot(['price', 'code'])->first();
}


@foreach($maintenance as $value)
   @if(!$product->maintenanceById($value->id)->isEmpty())
        <th>£ {{$product->maintenanceById($value->id)->pivot->price}}</th>

       @else
           <th></th>
       @endif
   @endforeach
```

Comment: You can use `->first()` and you should since, judging by the function name, it should return only one value. So, modify `...->withPivot(['price', 'code'])` to `...->withPivot(['price', 'code'])->first();`

Comment: @Andrew That gives me a bad method call exeption

Comment: Is there any way to force an object to be returned?

Comment: Try `->first()` without `->getResults()`